# String format doesn't work in python Tkinter text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, text, formatting

I'm working on an option calculator which could display various types of calculating methods and results. And I want to display those results in strings and format with fixed width. So I tried below codes.

```
Hieght = 600
Width = 800
interface = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(interface, height= Hieght, width=Width, bg='#266969')
canvas.pack()
interface.winfo_toplevel().title("Option Calculator")

lower_frame = tk.Frame(interface, bg='#266969', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relwidth = 0.8, relheight=0.5, anchor='n')

import tkinter.font as tkFont
customFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12)

output = tk.Text(lower_frame, font=customFont, fg='#ffffff', bg='#32a8a8')
output.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
out_Str = 'In B-S Formula\
            \nCall Value: {:>20.10f}\
            \nPut Value: {:>20.10f}\
            \n----------------------------------------------\
            \nIn Monte Carlo Simulation\
            \n{:<20s}{:>20s}{:>20s}\
            \n{:<20s}{:>20.10f}{:>20.10f}\
            \n{:<20s}{:>20.10f}{:>20.10f}\
            \n{:<20s}{:>20.10f}{:>20.10f}'.format \
            (Option1.CallPrice, \
                Option1.PutPrice, \
                    ' ', 'Call Option', 'Put Option', \
                        'Mean', Option1.Call_Mean_n, Option1.Put_Mean_n, \
                            'Upper bound', Option1.Call_upperI, Option1.Put_upperI, \
                                'Lower bound', Option1.Call_lowerI, Option1.Put_lowerI)

output.insert(tk.END, out_Str)
```

Those text just can't align in the way I want in the textbox area(Call Option and Put Option could align with the numbers and numbers could also align with each other). But when I copied the console out and pasted it to other places like textbook or here, it turned to be the way I want. The console (if I copied and pasted out) shows below. The console in the textbox area shows as the attached picture.

Consoles after pasting(the way I want to show)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNQIN.png)

Consoles in textbox(actually showed in tkinter)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l52Ou.png)

Could anyone tell me the reason resulting in the difference? And how to show the results as I want to?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use monospaced (fixed width) font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the font. Courier New, for example is a ttf, true type font where characters have equal width